# List as optional constructor parameter is null in Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, constructor

In the following example, why is `myList` `null` when no parameter is passed to the constructor?

I declare it as an empty ( growable ) list in the class.

```
class MyListClass {
  List myList = [];

  MyListClass({this.myList});
}

void main() {
  final obj = MyListClass();
  assert(obj.myList != null);
}
```

What is the best way to pass an optional list, but default to an empty list?

I know you can do the following, but maybe there is a better way?

```
MyListClass({this.myList}) {
  this.myList ??= [];
}
```

UDATE:
This is the intended behaviour and `null` the default if not given a value according to [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41574#issuecomment-616132948).

Comment: you didn't pass anything to the constructor which directs the value to the myList, that's why you are getting null(null == empty)

Comment: ok, i thought since it is optional, it should stay the same when no parameter was passed. i updated my question to find a best solution to solve this

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps. I posted a github issue.

Comment: post a link to that GitHub issue then

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41574

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** use the intializer:

```
class MyListClass {
  List myList;

  MyListClass({List list}) : myList = list ?? [];
}
```

Comment: this creates an unmodifiable list, i want to modify it

Comment: you can modify it but you can't set it to reference another list, isn't this what you want?

Comment: just tried it and got "Unhandled Exception: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list"

Comment: That is a solution, but it is a bit verbose and you cant pass a null value if you wanted to. I’m still surprised that my example did not work as expected. I filed a github issue on dart.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, as my error is the intended behaviour according to [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41574#issuecomment-616132948)

Comment: I saw the discussion and seems fair enough