# Initialise class parameter with default value

Tags: flutter, dart

How to initialise class parameter with default value

```
void main() {
  Test t = Test();
  print(t.l); //<-prints null, should print []
}

class Test{
  List l=[];
  Test({this.l});
}
```

I think this was working for me previously but for some reason it doesn't work now

```
void main() {
  Test t = Test();
  print(t.l); 
}

class Test{
  List l;
  Test({this.l}) : l = l ?? []; //<- as from GitHub this doesn't work either
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303278/optional-constructor-parameter-set-the-list-to-null-in-dart/61303489#61303489

Comment: @user that is not exactly an answer... I've got about 5 parameters which needs to have default value... that workaround suck.. sorry.. there must be a better way of doing it

Comment: There is no better way of doing it if you want not constant default value.

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov For some reason when I remove constructor then it works.. I'm positive that this was working previously. And for some reason I have removed all my constructors in my classes which were needed previously and everything works.. Is there some change in dart language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that as VyacheslavEgorov commented is by the initializer if you don't want const default value

and the reason it is working when you remove the constructor is according to [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41574#issuecomment-616132948) issue from github is:

> When you write f({this.x}) that means f({this.x : null}).
>
> Default initializers can only be constants, so your best bet is
>   f({List x}) : x = x ?? [];

so it would be like this:

```
class MyListClass {
  List myList;

  MyListClass({List myList}) : this.myList = myList ?? [];
}
```

Comment: look at my updated question.. because that doesn't work

Comment: you are doing it wrong

see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303278/list-as-optional-constructor-parameter-is-null-in-dart/61303489#61303489

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *either* take a parameter, or use a default value when the parameter is omitted, then you need to use something like your second example:

```dart
class MyListClass {
  final List myList;
  MyListClass({List myList}) : myList = myList ?? [];
}
```

(Note, it's not `this.myList` in the constructor parameter list because it's initialized by an initializer list entry instead).

If the default value is a compile-time constant, you can use it as an actual parameter default value:

```dart
class MyListClass {
  final List myList;
  MyListClass({this.myList = const []});
}
```

That only works when the default value is constant, and it still (until Null Safety is released) risks someone passing `null` as an explicit argument. The first example replaces `null` with `[]` no matter whether the `null` comes from omitting an argument or explicitly passing `null`.

(I tend to prefer the former approach, even when the default value is constant, because it handles explicit nulls. With Null Safety, that'll no longer be necessary).

Comment: Thanks... That is very helpful.. to be honest I get a bit confused at the time I wrote this question. Perhaps from other programming languages or something...